# jQuery Mobile Label sitting on right

Tags: jquery-mobile

This should fairly simple question for a jQuery mobile expert. As you can see in the picture my button label "call" is not centered. How can I move it to the left?
[image]

```
    <div class="ui-block-c"> <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Call</a><br> </div>
```

Comment: Could you give us some of your (relevant) code?

Comment: I am trying not sure what is wrong with stack website, just added it.

Comment: Okay, remember to indent the code with four spaces before the start of each line

Comment: Maybe try creating a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which shows your problem, including all the relevent code

Comment: Here is one with the jQuery Mobile dependencies already added: http://jsfiddle.net/jofish999/qe0mpmy7/ (just go there, fork it, and add your code

Comment: You can see it here http://chapar.parseapp.com/ just click on the dial pad button.

Comment: just did it. you need Mozilla though, Chrome only shows "..." instead of "Call"

Comment: just added to jsfiddle